# Get all comments authored by a Google Plus user

Tags: google-plus

Google Plus API makes it possible to get all comments for an activity if you know the activity id: 
https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/reading#getting_a_list_of_comments_on_a_specific_post

But in my case I don't know the activity ids. I just know the id of the user, that has written the comments.

How can I find all comments authored by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google+ API does not have such a feature. You could try searching for the user's name but that would find a lot of false positives.